# How to set custom height of one row in grid?

Tags: html, css

I want to set custom height in one specific row in grid gallery view.

```
.grid-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

I have 3 columns and each row (I have dynamic amout of rows) has got 250px height. Now I want to add one div with `.grid-title` class to have e.g. 100px height and of course this div muse span 3 colums to have 100% width of grid-container.

I have tried something like this but it doesn't change the height of 3 colums. Even with `display: grid` it's not working too.

```
.grid-title {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}
```

It should looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

Working pen:

https://codepen.io/freestyle09/pen/oNvGywK

Comment: Can you add minimal working html and css code ?

Comment: I have added link to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found solution. When we want to set dynamic height of few divs inside grid container we must use `minmax()` function.

```
grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px,auto);
```

After this we can manually set height of our grid items:

```
.item {
    height: 320px;
}
```

Here's working example:
https://codepen.io/freestyle09/pen/YzKrjrx

Thanks to **hisbvdis** for pointing me a way to find an answer

Answer (score 2):

> I have 3 columns and each row

If you have fixed amount of columns, why you set `auto-fit` value to `grid-template-columns` property?

> I want to add one div with .grid-title class to have e.g. 100px

If custom item will always be in one place, you can set this row height in `grid-template-rows: 250px 250px 100px;` plus `grid-auto-rows: 250px;`: https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/wvwrXye

If custom item can be in random place, you can set `grid-auto-rows: 100px` plus add `grid-rows: span 2;` properties to items: https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/vYBerjL

Comment: Yeah you are right and what If I want have dynamic amout of divs with 100px ?? I don't want to place manually div with title

Comment: I don’t understand what it means "I don't want to place manually div with title". I'll try to guess. Something like this? https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/LYPzrqV?editors=1100

Comment: Yeah It's almost perfect, but now height of image is: 100 x 2 + grid-gap, what If i want 290px height of image and 50px height of title? You know what I want to do? I want to don't change images height and count it from rows(span x) but only to change divs with class title

Comment: see this example: https://codepen.io/freestyle09/pen/gOYGjbx?editors=1100

Comment: How to change auto-rows height in custom divs ?

Answer (score -1):

Define grid template row of your grid container to be 50px which is multiple of both 100 px (grid-title class) and 250px (default row size you needed). Each row will have a height of 50 px as we defined. Now, we can overwrite for independent class with span 2 (ie., 50px * 2) or span 5 (ie., 50px * 5) which will give a height of 100 px and 250 px for those classes. Check mine below CSS properties which will satisfy your conditions.

```
.grid-gallery {
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.grid-gallery > div{
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-gallery .grid-title {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
/*  Here some rules  */
}
.image-gallery {
  grid-row: span 5;
}
```